# How to get ID part fron an attribute on XSL

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

The question is how to get the part from ID like this:

```
id="sometext_foldername-somesection-of-somepart"
```

I need to get the foldername from this ID. How can I get it? Sorry for my English.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The answer is

```
substring-before(substring-after(@id,'_'),'-somesection-')
```

Thanks!